# Norm of the linear operator $T: C[0,\pi] \to C[0, \pi]$ defined by $Tf(t) =\int_{0}^t f(s) \ ds$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $Tf(t) =\int_{0}^t f(s) \ ds$. Show that $Tf(t)$ defines a continuous linear operator $T: C[0,\pi] \to C[0, \pi]$ and determine the norm of $T$.

Let $f,g \in C[0,\pi]$, then $T(f+g)(t) = \int_{0}^t(f+g)(t) \ ds = \int_{0}^t f(t) + g(t)  \ ds = \int_{0}^t f(t) \ ds + \int_{0}^t g(t) \ ds = Tf(t) + Tg(t)$.

If $c$ is a scalar, then $T(cf(t)) = \int_{0}^t cf(t) \ ds = c\int_{0}^tf(t) \ ds = cTf(t)$.

So $T$ is linear. Also $\|Tf\| = \sup \left\{ |Tf| \mid f \in C[0, \pi], \|f\|_\infty = 1  \right \}$

and $$|Tf(t)| = \left| \int_{0}^t f(t) \ ds \right| \le \int_{0}^t |f(t)| \ ds \le \int_{0}^t \|f\|_\infty \ ds = \|f\|_\infty \int_{0}^t ds = t \le \pi$$

so $|Tf|$ is bounded and thus $T$ is continuous as it's Lipschitz.

I would now want to show that actually $\|Tf\| = \pi$, but if I take $f \equiv 1$, then $$Tf(t) = \int_{0}^t f(t) \ ds = \int_{0}^t ds = t \ge 0$$ so I just get that $$\|Tf\| \ge 0 \text{ and } \|Tf\| \le \pi$$

but not the equality. What can be done here to show equality?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Norm of the Linear (Integral) Operator on $C[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/960939/norm-of-the-linear-integral-operator-on-c0-1) (the key in the comment of the answer was)

Comment: (the key in the comment of the answer was "The bound holds for any $t$")

Comment: Not sure what is meant by "there is no loss" in the answer there. @AnneBauval

Comment: Oh you are right, *that* was the key for you! It means: "the inequality becomes an equality".

Comment: If $Tf(x) = x$, then $\Vert Tf \Vert = \pi$ as we are on $[0,\pi]$. As the constant function has norm $1$, we get that $\Vert T \Vert \geq \pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon you were in the right track. Since I myself am learning Functional Analysis I'll replicate your reasoning just to be sure of what I'm doing and allow people to edit my post if needed. Indeed,

$$ ||Tf(t)||_\infty = \Big|\Big|\int_0^t f(s)ds \Big|\Big|_\infty = \sup_{t \in [0,\pi]} \Big| \int_0^t f(s) ds \Big| \leq \sup_{t \in [0,\pi]} \int_0^t |f(s)| ds \leq ||f||_\infty \sup_{t \in [0,\pi]} \int_0^t 1 ds = ||f||_\infty \pi$$

Therefore, $||T|| \leq \pi$. Now, let us consider $f(s) = 1$. Then,

$$||Tf(t)||_\infty = \sup_{t \in [0,\pi]} \Big| \int_0^t 1 ds \Big| = \sup_{t \in [0,\pi]} t = \pi$$

Since we found a function in $C[0,\pi]$ for which $||Tf(t)||_\infty = \pi$, then $||T|| = \pi$.